# Riding along with the windows down

Tags: synonyms

I have met a kind of expression that I am unable to understand. The full sentence I met is "Most of the automotive stock analysts were, and are, happily riding along with the windows down." I myself have tried to google it but I just understand the original meaning as "driving with the windows of the car down". But it doesn't make sense in this sentence. So how can I understand in this context?

Comment: They're riding along having a good time (which is what the open windows description means) and enjoying themselves--maybe not being as analytical or critical as they could be.  It's hard to tell without more context, though.

Comment: I think it is obvious what they are saying but I am not aware that I have ever seen it before as an idiom and I cannot find it referenced anywhere.

Comment: Building on Xanne's comment, this expression can also mean they are carefree, enjoying life to the fullest, or, that they are clueless with respect to the economic indicators for the future of their industry.  Per Xanne, it's hard to tell out of context.